# Freebase with own data?

Tags: freebase

I have been looking for an autosuggest search script and I have finally found one that I like, the only problem is that I cannot find a way to get it to run off our database results.

Is there any way to customize this script so that it runs from our own database, and not off the freebase pre-defined data types?

http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest

Comment: perhaps email the coder direct, if u search for daepark on google he has a github page with his email. He is also a member on here search for daepark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried overriding service_url and service_path ? There are also the corresponding params for the flyout service. It's documented in the docs that you pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

As masouras says, you can override service_url and service_path, but that's not particularly helpful unless you have another service which provides the same APIs as Freebase.

Dae Park recently posted [a recipe](http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2011-May/006513.html) to the Freebase mailing list which might help - however, I'm not aware of anyone who's actually managed to get Suggest working with anything other than Freebase.